# location header scheme, get http:// but want https://

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine

I have a spring boot service and an angular app running on app engine. I'm using a `dispatch.yaml` that redirects `*/api/*` to the service.

The service adds a Location header to a (http) response but it does only work because the code overrides the scheme:

```
    URI uri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequestUri ()
        .scheme ("https")
        .replacePath ("/api/processor/{id}")
        .buildAndExpand(processingId)
        .encode ()
        .toUri ();

    return ResponseEntity
        .accepted ()
        .location (uri)
        .body (processingId);
```

Calling `fromCurrentRequestUri()` helps to get the hostname of the frontend and not the service but it does use `http://` and not `https://`. The `scheme("https")` forces it to https.

It makes sense that it gets http as the service is running with http "inside" app engine. The http location is correct from the service perspective but wrong from the frontend perspective.

Is there a way to rewrite the Location header by some app engine configuration to https:// so it is correct for the frontend?

Comment: Do you want to force HTTPS? and are you using App engine Standard or flex? and which version of Java are you using, 8 or 11?

Comment: I need https://, calling the url given by the Location header with http:// will fail. Standard, Java 11. But I would like to NOT hardcode it in the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to force all the HTTP requests to get redirected to HTTPS this is done with [handlers](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref) in the app.yaml

by adding the following lines to the app.yaml

```
- url: /.*
  secure: always
  script: auto
```

Comment: This works on the frontend itself but it doesn't work for the url from the Location header. Maybe because of the dispatch.yaml. Don't know. It doesn't have any effect when added to the service. So I guess, I'm stuck with the hardcoded https://.

Comment: I edited the answer, I tested doing CURL, by taking out the redirect code I was able to get a not found on http and only got answer by https

Comment: I tested again, it seems to work if I directly talk to the service. It does not work when the `dispatch.yaml` is active. Strange. Anyway, i will add a gateway for another reason and it will allow me to handle this issue as well.